# UnitTesting a WebClient in Windows Phone 7

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7, event-handling, webclient

I have some of WebClient Requests in my App and want to check the parsing of the retrieved data in a unit test. How Do I wait in the WP7 Silverlight UnitTestFramework for the event client_DownloadStringCompleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completely wrong approach here. You're unit testing the wrong thing.

What you want to do, is to move your parsing of the data out to another class, and define a interface, say:

```
interface IWebParser { MyResult Parse(string input); }
```

and then inject that into your class, and in your `DownloadStringCompleted` event, call `iWebParser.Parse(e.Result)`.

Now you can test your implementations of the IWebParser. And replace it.

Unit Testing isn't meant to test implementation specific code. You might as well just use a accessor and test a private method then!

Answer (score 4):

My approach to this has been to introduce a wrapper class around `WebClient` (well, I actually used `HttpWebRequest` in the end, as `WebClient` did too much in the UI thread...) implementing an interface. I could then create a `FakeWebClient` implementing `IWebClient`, allowing me to validate the URLs that were being fetched, and responding with errors, success cases etc as desired.

It's unfortunate that quite a few APIs in .NET aren't easily testable / fakable :(

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should not test with HTTP requests. But to write such tests anyway eventually this link will help you (asynchronous testing):

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/03/asynchronous-testing/